# Use newline='' with click.open_file() to support OS-indepent new-lines & CSVs

Tags: python, command-line-interface, file-handling

The PyPi `click` library has an [open_file()](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/utils/#intelligent-file-opening) function which is preferred over Python's `open()` function since it can "intelligently open stdin/stdout as well as any other file" (e.g. when the filename is specified as `-`).

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to support the `newline` argument of Python's built-in [open()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#open) function which is required by Python's standard CSV module to properly [handle new-lines in an OS-independent manner](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#id3). Without this, CSVs generated on Windows have extra empty lines between each row.

Is it possible to use click's `open_file()` to read/write CSVs in an OS-independent manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the issue discussions on Github this is not something `click` will natively support:

- https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/426
- https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/1711

I've found the following work-around to work for me:

```py
if output_path == '-':
    # Specifically use click's open_file only for its stdout stream
    file_ctx_manager = click.open_file(output_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
else:
    # Use open() directly for actual files because the CSV requires newline='' to be OS-independent
    file_ctx_manager = open(output_path, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8')

with file_ctx_manager as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    writer.writerow([])
```